# Xcode: macros breaking completion/highlighting

Tags: xcode, parsing, syntax-highlighting, code-completion, preprocessor-directive

From the [Xcode Docs](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html#llvm-compiler):

> Syntax highlighting, code completion, and every other index-driven
>   feature is handled by the LLVM parser. If the compiler knows about a
>   symbol, so does the Xcode IDE.

but none of these "index-driven features" are working for me when writing code inside of a preprocessor directive.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

Examples:

When building with *Unused Parameter* warnings turned on, tons of warnings are generated even when said parameter *is* used.  The code in this specific screenshot is from Apples `Reachability.m` and is unmodified.  Notice that syntax highlighting is also nonexistent here:

[image: Warnings]

*Correct* completion inside `#if`:

[image: Correct Code Completion]

But, *incorrect* completion inside `#else`:

[image: Incorrect Code Completion]

It half works with local variables:

[image: Broken Parsing in UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait Macro]

But breaks again when calling something declared outside of the current method scope:

[image: Broken Parsing in UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait Macro]

[Another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwRZE.gif)
[Another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCZLg.png)

Can anyone please tell me how (or even *if*) this can be fixed?

Comment: Sounds like a [radar](http://bugreport.apple.com) waiting to be filed! :)

Comment: @Bavarious I thought about that, but then I discovered that this happens in all versions of xcode with any compiler, so I would imagine someone had to have already reported it (if this is a bug) and if not a bug, there must be someone who has figured out how to fix it.  If I don't get an answer with a fix here though, I'll definately file one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug and is now fixed in Xcode Version 4.3.1 (4E1019).

Comment: Thanks for adding this. Sadly I'm stuck on 4.2 (Snow Leopard For Life), but at least there's a path to sanity.

Comment: I can't say it's fixed for all. I still get similar (or same) problem in XCode 5.1. My scenario may be a little different, I have different collection of headers for different targets, and changing the target each time messes it up. Cleaning / rebuilding doesn't help. Only solution is to relaunch the XCode.

Answer (score 2):

XCode actually evaluates the conditions on preprocessor directives and only does highlighting/completing for the code inside the currently true condition. For example

[image]

[image]

Syntax highlighting, autocompletion, and warnings (unsused variable warning in this case) don't work in the untrue condition.

I opened a question asking how to make XCode do all these things on both sides of the condition, but no luck so far.
[XCode syntax highlighting in both conditions of preprocessor #if #else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29497226/1700562)

For the record I do not think this behavior is a bug. I can imagine cases where it would be extremely frustrating to be getting errors on code that won't be compiled. It would however be nice to be able to edit both sides of these conditions without having to manipulate your macro definitions.

Answer (score 1):

@chown, I think "If the compiler knows about a symbol...exactly as they are when building." indicate that compiler parses the code and follow the all preprocessor conditions. In such case, compiler will not notice variable usage inside of such `#ifdef` where condition has failed.

This also explains why it is "works fine in the `#else`.".

You can try to use UNUSED macro, but you will have to disable warning for "Unused values":

```
#define UNUSED(a) a
...
-(void)test:(id)argument
{
    UNUSED(argument);
#ifdef AAA
    NSLog(@"arg:%@", argument);
#endif    
}
```